# error services irc mysql

Tags: c++, c

I am trying to install IRC services and it's giving me the following error, I was wondering if anyone has seen this before and has a solution 
Thanks

```
g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..     -g -O3 -Wall -Igoogle/sparsehash/src/ -I/usr/include/mysql -MT base64.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/base64.Tpo -c -o base64.o base64.cpp
In file included from base64.cpp:21:0:
stdafx.h:64:19: error fatal: mysql.h: No existe el archivo o el directorio
compilación terminada.
make[2]: *** [base64.o] Error 1
make[2]: se sale del directorio «/home/yeremay/services-master/Nucleo»
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: se sale del directorio «/home/yeremay/services-master»`




make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the mysql.h file in `/usr/include/mysql`, that's what the error message said.

or you change it to `-I/usr/include`